# Having preprocessor directive as part of statement

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, constexpr

We moved to a new compilation environment and all of sudden I started seeing this error "expected expression" on this statement:

```
enum {
  PROJX,
  PROJY,
  PROJW
};

constexpr int PLATFORM =
#if defined(X)
  PROJX
#elif defined(Y)
  PROJY 
#elif defined(W)
  PROJW
#endif
  ;
```

The error is pointing to the last semicolon.

Is this related to a specific c++11/14/17 standard?

Comment: Are you sure either `X`, `Y` or `W` are defined? Seems to me like in your new configuration non of those are defined so you have `constexpr int PLATFORM = ;`.

Comment: Might be that X, Y and W are all undefined so the result is `constexpr int PLATFORM = ;`?

Comment: Try adding an `#else`.

Comment: ...especially, try adding an `#else` section containing a `#error ...` message.

Comment: _"Is this related to a specific c++11/14/17 standard?"_ Nope.

Comment: _"Is this the answer section?"_ Nope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No standard changes this behavior. My guess is that none of the three are defined and you end up with:

```
constexpr int PLATFORM = ;
```

You can test this by either adding an `#else` and a default value / `#error` or checking the output of your compiler after the preprocessor has ran.

Comment: Comment answering the question gets the upvote. Answer answering the question gets the downvote. Oh how I love you SO.

Comment: People are strange. You don't even have to be a stranger; that just makes it worse.